# What late payment fees would apply for a self-employed person in the UK on contract with a French company?

Tags: self-employment, european-union

I am owed payment for a contract from a French company, which is now 6 months late. The UK and EU law both stipulates 30 days is the maximum amount of time that can pass before late payment fees are charged (interest and compensation).

The EU site on the issue appears to only be for countries in the EU (which the UK no longer is). Does it apply to people working in countries outside of the EU? Some of the language on the page suggests it doesn't, but there is an option in the dropdown menu to select the UK as a creditor country: https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/finance-funding/making-receiving-payments/late-payment/#business

Should UK law apply? Or do neither of the laws apply for charging late payment fees? I would like to recoup my losses but am unsure how best to proceed.

The contract states the payment will be made in 30 days, and doesn't stipulate any particular law that the contract is governed by. The company is registered in France and therefore working on the basis that French law governs the contract.

Comment: I suspect without knowing in which country the contract was formed, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: The company is registered in France and therefore working on the basis that French law governs the contract. @simonb